# Can I post a good screenshot for my favorite sci fi show?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

What are the rules to posting screenshots to our favorite tv show? For example, I'm attaching one now for Star Gate.

Could I possibly preface it with, "what are they thinking in this shot?" Is there a better site for this sort of thing? Thanks

[image: sam from star gate atlantis]

Comment: What would you hope to accomplish by doing so?  This is a Q&A site, not an image board.

Comment: He's thinking "where is the bathroom." She's thinking "I'm glad I know where the bathroom is."

Seriously though, if you want to discuss things, do it in the chat room.

Comment: Why are people down voting my question? I'm trying to find out what and where to post things.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts on meta a down vote is a vote no, not and indication that the question is bad.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm pretty sure posting a screen shot within a question is fine. You just need to make sure the question you are asking is appropriate for the site.

Something like, "What are they thinking for this shot" is probably NOT an example of an appropriate question.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can post a screenshot in a question or an answer. But keep in mind that this is a [question and answers site](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/about), not a discussion forum. As it says in the [FAQ](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask),

> If your motivation for asking the question is “I would like to participate in a discussion about ........”, then you should not be asking here.

Answer (score 5):

I take it that you are wanting to interact and entertain others with a screenshoot. If that's the case, Jack is correct. Scifi chat is a better spot for humor.